# Create a List of saves from one button

Tags: java, android, xml, string, button

I need help with my project. I need to be able to press a save button that uses shared preferences, and every time I press that button, I need it to take the saved data and stack it underneath each other like a list. The key value is "result". So the save button takes the string and integer and places it onto my Main activity XML layout. But, if I press save again with different integers or string it will replace the original string and integer I had originally saved. I want it to be able to keep the original string and integer if i save it for the first time and make a new string and integer underneath the original if i do a second time and so on forever. Please help!

This is under my saving activity:

```
    public void save(View view){

    Date date = new Date();
    String stringDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("result",String.format(stringDate, date) + " - " + text_view5.getText().toString());

    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

This is under my loading activity:

```
    resultPhysical = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String physicalresult = sharedPreferences.getString("result", DEFAULT);
    String physicalresult2= sharedPreferences.getString("result2", DEFAULT);
    if (physicalresult.equals(DEFAULT)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        resultPhysical.setText(physicalresult);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily save them, just create an extra variable that refers to the size of saved results so that you can loop over them. To start saving, get the size then save with the index

```
int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("size", 0); // if it doesn't exist, get 0
// then save the result like
editor.putString("result" + String.valueOf(size), String.format(stringDate, date) + " - " + text_view5.getText().toString()); // just add index to result
// then increase the size
editor.putInt("size", ++size);
editor.commit();
```

To load the results

```
StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
int size = int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("size", 0); // get the size to start looping
if(size == 0){ // if results are empty
    // show toast there is no saved result
} else { //start looping
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        String temp = sharedPreferences.getString("result" + String.valueOf(i), DEFAULT);
        results.append(temp + " ");
    }
    resultPhysical.setText(results.toString());
}
```

Comment: hmm..it seems like it should  be working. No errors not even in the logcat but for some reason it won't change the default text even after i save

Comment: @JoshSmith Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I used TextView id:home to say "No data found" when there is no data. So I need to make the array list show up on that TextView...i think

Comment: @JoshSmith No, you don't need to set the whole array to the TextView, I just wrote that to show how you can retrieve the whole results if you want. To get the last saved use `String lastResult = sharedPreferences.getString("result" + String.valueOf(size-1), DEFAULT);`

Comment: How can i get it to display EVERY save in one array list inside a textview?

Comment: @JoshSmith aaah, like showing the history? you wanna the whole results in the TextView? I will edit the code

Comment: @JoshSmith Done editing, now the loading will show the whole saved results inside a TextView separated by a space.

Comment: thank you so much, but how can i space each history by an entire line? Because right now they are side by side and too close

Comment: @JoshSmith just replace `temp + " "` with `temp + "\n"`, if the answer is helpful, can you mark it as accepted? :)